# Pinch Zoom Element Only

Tags: jquery, touch, pinchzoom

Is it possible to isolate pinch zoom to just one element? Like if I have a top main menu placed over a map image under it, can the pinch zoom gesture just zoom the map and leave the menu un-zoomed and fixed in place at the top of the page? Something similar to the way Google Maps in a browser works. If someone could point me in the right direction here it'd be much appreciated. Nothing I have tried has worked so far on iOS.

Comment: You would need to isolate the specific Pinch Zoom event and then override it to perform the scaling of an element versus Zoom of the Window. I believe Google Maps uses an iFrame so the Pinch Zoom event is targeting that  page and not the current page.

Comment: Thank you Twisty - I have mocked it up in an iFrame now and its looking good. Scrolling just fine. But now I have to figure out how to disable the main page zoom and only allow it on the iFrame - any ideas there?